# Merge these similar preg_replace regex variations

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've got a set of three `preg_replace` functions giving me the outcome I want, but I don't know if there's a way to make the code more efficient. Is there a way to merge these variations?

```
$content = "A really long string with paragraph breaks, html tags, spaces, etc."
$string = preg_replace('/\.\n[A-Z](.+)/', '.', strip_tags($content));
$string = preg_replace('/\.\r[A-Z](.+)/', '.', strip_tags($string));
$string = preg_replace('/\.\s[A-Z](.+)/', '.', strip_tags($string));
```

I don't need anyone to do my work for me. I just need pointers as I can figure it out once I know what options there are to work with. All for the sake of cleaner, more efficient code.

UPDATE

The final code looks like this.

```
$content = "A really long string with paragraph breaks, html tags, spaces, etc."
$string = strip_tags($content);
$string = trim(preg_replace('/[\t\n\r\s]+/', ' ', $string));
$string = preg_replace('/\.[\t\n\r\s][A-Z](.+)/i', '.', $string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would clean this up:

```
$content = "A really long string with paragraph breaks and shift spaces, etc."
$string = preg_replace('/\.[\n\r\s][A-Z](.+)/', '.', strip_tags($content));
```

But what I don’t understand is the role `strip_tags` plays in this. Is there more to your code that you’re not showing? I like to keep things simple & debuggable in PHP so this is how I would factor in `strip_tags`:

```
$content = "A really long string with paragraph breaks and shift spaces, etc."
$content = strip_tags($content);
$string = preg_replace('/\.[\n\r\s][A-Z](.+)/', '.', $content);
```

That might seem like a subtle difference, but by placing `strip_tags` on a separate line, you can turn it on or off by commenting it out.

But that said, the more I look at your code the less I understand what the input should be & what output is desired. I mean, your regex would be this:

```
/\.[\n\r\s][A-Z](.+)/
```

What would that replace exactly? And why just `A-Z`? Why not `A-Za-z`? Or perhaps add the `i` modifier to the regex so it is case insensitive like this:

```
/\.[\n\r\s][A-Z](.+)/i
```

Comment: Dude, I appreciate all this. I'm not a PHP guy, so I've got piece meal for now. This helps me clean things up. I'll update in a moment after some testing.

Comment: Nope. I did my work and it works. I just want to learn how to clean things up.

Comment: Your last suggestion to add the `i` modifier helped.